# Grep for regular letters and special characters

Tags: grep

I'm trying to isolate lines that contain the following: '[Homosapiens]' from a file.
My file looks something like this:

```
br
blabla
>blabldi[Homosapiens]
>skadlfjkl[Musmusculus]
```

I only want to isolate the third line.
I have tried the following:

```
grep -F '\*[Homosapiens]' mytext.txt
```

and

```
fgrep '\*[Homosapiens]' mytext.txt
```

but both are not working.
Can anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What about the following:

```
fgrep "[Homosapiens]" mytext.txt
```

Or:

```
grep "\[Homosapiens\]" mytext.txt
```

Two remarks:

- `grep` (or whatever of its family members `fgrep`, `egrep`, ...) search for an entry inside a line of text, so there is no need to try to fit the whole line inside your `grep` expression.
- The square brackets have a special meaning (`grep [a-e]` means a search for all letters from 'a' to 'e'). Using a backslash in front of a square bracket disables that feature and gives you the opportunity to look for a square bracket.

Comment: Right, but note that the closing `]` does not have to be escaped in the second regex-powered version.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Are you saying that, for that version, the second backslash is just obsolete or is it wrong?

Comment: It is not wrong, it is just not necessary to escape `]` when outside of a bracket expression in a POSIX regex.